# Disabling the arrows that appear in pgfplots on the axes

Tags: pgfplots

By default in PGFplots, when axes are only shown in the bottom left corner, arrows appear at the end of the ends of axes lines.  How can I change the defaults so these arrows do not appear?

Edit: Example code that produces plots with arrows at the tips of the axes lines

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
   \begin{axis}[axis x line=middle,axis y line=middle]
      \addplot {x^3};
   \end{axis} 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you please add to your question a complete and minimal example code illustrating the behaviour mentioned?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use

```
\pgfplotsset{ every non boxed x axis/.append style={x axis line style=-},
     every non boxed y axis/.append style={y axis line style=-}}
```

A complete MWE follows

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}       

\pgfplotsset{ every non boxed x axis/.append style={x axis line style=-},
     every non boxed y axis/.append style={y axis line style=-}}

\begin{document}

      \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}
          \addplot expression{x};
        \end{axis}
      \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I don't see difference in the output with or without the `\pgfplotsset`.

Comment: Your code won't produce the expected result.

Comment: I don't see a difference either, but I'm hoping the answer looks something like this.

Comment: @Jake has a correction to your pgfplotsset command that makes it work for me.  Could you correct your answer?

Comment: @GonzaloMedina I posted before a MWE was available. I would delete my answer, but it has been accepted.

Comment: @Jeff the moral of the story is: post a MWE :) I would have been able to fix the code myself if I had seen what you were working with

Comment: @cmhughes: Sorry about that; I'm new here and still getting the hang of things. Thanks everyone for your help.

Answer (score 31):

There are "starred" versions of the `axis x line` and `axis lines` keys that switch off the arrow tips.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
   \begin{axis}[axis lines*=middle]
      \addplot {x^3};
   \end{axis} 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Simplest and best way, it seems. Would be a better accepted answer.

Comment: This has side-effects if you want to change something about the labels. The best one is to just set `axis line style={-}`.

Comment: @RicardoCruz Thanks for the tip! That looks better. The ticks go through the axes lines your way. In this answer they are only to the right/above the axes lines.

Comment: It is useful for me after more than 10 years. Thanks!

Answer (score 16):

You can use the `axis line style` option; an example showing the axis with and without the arrows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
   \begin{axis}[axis x line=middle,axis y line=middle]
      \addplot {x^3};
   \end{axis} 
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
   \begin{axis}[axis x line=middle,axis y line=middle,axis line style={-}]
      \addplot {x^3};
   \end{axis} 
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

As **Jake** mentioned in a comment, to globally disable the arrow tips, you can use

```
\pgfplotsset{ every non boxed x axis/.append style={x axis line style=-} }
```

Comment: This example works great, but is there a way to make this the default 'axis line style' for every plot?  I'm generating many figures using matlab2tikz and would like to set this globally in the TeX file if possible.

Comment: @Jake That seemed to do the trick.  Thanks.

Comment: Although Gonzalo's answer works, I would prefer to see cmhughes answer corrected as that was more in the style of what I was looking for (although Gonzalo's is a perfectly valid answer).